# Scala- How to do GroupBy and Sum on case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by

I'm fairly new to this.. My problem is: for a case class `case class testclass(date_key: String , amount: Int, type:String, condition1:String, condition2: String)`

In `Dataframe df`, I'm trying to sum the `amount`, groupby it by `type:String`, when a row's `condition1=condition2`

I'm trying to define a function but how should I do this? Many thanks!

```
 `def sumAmount (t: testclass): Int = { 
      if (condition1==condition2) 
   {

   } else {
       "na"
   }
  }`
```

Comment: Are you trying to `groupBy` **only** when `condition1==condition2` holds? Can you show the input Dataset and the output when the condition holds and when it does not? That'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you already have a `dataframe` using `case class`

```
case class testclass(date_key: String , amount: Int, types: String, condition1: String, condition2: String)
```

For test purpose I have created a test `dataframe`

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition1"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition1"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition2"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition1"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition1"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition1"),
  testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition2")
).toDF
```

which should give you

```
+----------+------+------+----------+----------+
|date_key  |amount|types |condition1|condition2|
+----------+------+------+----------+----------+
|2015-01-01|332   |types |condition1|condition1|
|2015-01-01|332   |types |condition1|condition1|
|2015-01-01|332   |types |condition1|condition2|
|2015-01-01|332   |types2|condition1|condition1|
|2015-01-01|332   |types2|condition1|condition1|
|2015-01-01|332   |types2|condition1|condition1|
|2015-01-01|332   |types2|condition1|condition2|
+----------+------+------+----------+----------+
```

Now you want to `groupBy` `types` column and `sum` the `amount` when `condition1 = condtion2`. For that you can `filter` only the rows where `condition1=condition2` and do `groupBy` and `aggregation` of `sum` as following

```
df.filter($"condition1" === $"condition2")
  .groupBy("types")
  .agg(sum("amount").as("sum"))
  .show(false)
```

you should have the desired result

```
+------+---+
|types |sum|
+------+---+
|types |664|
|types2|996|
+------+---+
```

**Updated**

If you want to work with `dataSet` instead of `dataframe` you can use `.toDS` instead of `.toDF` as

```
scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> case class testclass(date_key: String , amount: Int, types: String, condition1: String, condition2: String)
defined class testclass

scala> val ds = Seq(
     | testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition1"),
     |       testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition1"),
     |       testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types", "condition1", "condition2"),
     |       testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition1"),
     |       testclass("2015-01-01", 332, "types2", "condition1", "condition2")
     |     ).toDS
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[testclass] = [date_key: string, amount: int ... 3 more fields]
```

You can see that its a `dataset` instead of `dataframe`

Rest of the steps are explained as above.

Comment: Thanks and an upvote. But I'm trying to work on Dataset other than dataframe, as I try to keep the types for the value rather than map them back to certain types/ That's why I try to create functions

Comment: I'm able to convert from a df to a case class, but I dont know how to write the function. So I guess my problem is not .to DS?

Comment: why do you want to write a function for? Can you clarify a little bit.

Comment: because I want to use dataset instead of dataframe?

Comment: see my updated answer if that answers yours confustion :)

Comment: So you could use filter on DS too? Thanks! I will try it soon

Comment: DataSet and DataFrame are same. DataSet are optimized and type safe. :)

Answer (score -1):

- You need to filter you data collection first where `data.condition1.equals(data.condition2)`
- then `groupBy` datatype, which gives you dataType as key and list of case classes as values
- then finally sum the amount on the list of values

Example (*no spark involved*)

```
case class MyData(dataKey: String, amount: Int, dataType: String, condition1: String, condition2: String)

val grouped = List(MyData("a", 1000, "type1", "matches1", "matches1"),
  MyData("b", 1000, "type1", "matches1", "matches1"),
  MyData("c", 1000, "type1", "matches1", "matches2"),
  MyData("d", 1000, "type2", "matches1", "matches1")
).filter(data => data.condition1.equals(data.condition2))
  .groupBy(_.dataType)
  .map{ case (dataType, values) =>
    dataType -> values.map(_.amount).sum
  }.toMap

grouped("type1") shouldBe 2000
grouped("type2") shouldBe 1000
```